# Is there something like unzip -t for install4j installers?

Tags: install4j

The installers I build with install4j are going to be distributed out to multiple (sometimes hundreds) of appliances in a datacenter by an update program.  In our current implementation these files are "tested" for corruption with unzip -t.  I realize we could compare md5sums on the files but that adds an extra bit of overhead we'd like to avoid in our build process.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the condition expression `!Boolean.getBoolean("testRun")` to all your screens, you could execute the installer in command line mode with the arguments

-J-DtestRun=true -c

Then the installer would do a dry run, without any modifications to the system. Of course this would only work on a compatible target system.